# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/AbstractResponse

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Error started coming after i have upgraded my existing Production Kafka Cluster from Kafka0.8.2.1 to Kafka0.11.0.1.

It is unable to initialize kafka config for the new version of library.

In our project we are using storm to process realtime Kafka topics

```
Storm Version: 1.0.2
Storm-Kafka version: 1.0.2
Kafka-Version: 0.11.0.1 with Scala 2.11
```

Error logs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/AbstractResponse
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.java:36) ~[storm-kafka-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.java:47) ~[storm-kafka-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaConfig.<init>(TridentKafkaConfig.java:30) ~[storm-kafka-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
```

I am not sure about the main reason of but i suspect it with the version of scala used for kafka 11.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and, after spending several days (!), I finally got a solution I want to share whith you

The problem was the version of the kafka-clients package in project's eclipse referenced libraries. Despite using maven updating, it kept the 0.8.2.1 version. But the right one was the 0.10.2.1. So, I imported the right library from maven using

`mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2.1`

and removed the old version from the classpath and it works !
Hope this helps !
Michel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients on the classpath as well as org.apache.kafka:kafka. Tools like Maven should do this for you, but maybe you're handling dependencies manually? If so you'll want to compare the dependencies here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/0.8.2.1 to the new dependency set here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/0.11.0.1